Adding to Import-Excel Array
I have a list of Windows extensions that have imported into PowerShell via the Import-Excel command.
The Excel file is structured like this:
| Ext     | DotExt  | Application                  | Active   | Inactive | Skipped |
| ------- | ------- | ---------------------------- | -------- | -------- | ------- |
| AAC     | .AAC    |  Windows audio               | 0        | 0        | 0       |
| ACCDB   | .ACCDB  |  MS Access database file     | 0        | 0        | 0       |
| ACCDE   | .ACCDEB |  MS Access execute-only file | 0        | 0        | 0       |
| PDF     | .PDF    |  Adobe Acrobat File          | 0        | 0        | 0       |
| DOCX    | .DOCX   |  Microsoft Word              | 0        | 0        | 0       |
...

$Win_FileExtsList = Import-Excel -Path $Win_FileExtsListExcel

$Win_FileExtsList.GetType() produces:

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

I pass $Win_FileExtsList to a function that reads a file list to count the number of the extensions of that type.
The file passed into the function is defined as such:
function Set-Extensions {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [array] $FileExtsList,
        ...

If an extension is not present, I want to add it to the array so it can be included in the count.  This count will be added to the Excel file at a later time.
I defined a new array matching the Excel file and want to add it to the list.
$New = ([array]@{Ext=$DocExt;DotExt=$DotExt;Application="update";Active=1;Inactive=0;Skipped=0})

When I try and add the $New to $FileExtsList ($Win_FileExtsList) nothing happens.  Other times when
I try and add it to the list, it comes in as a hashtable.
I have tried $FileExtsList += $New and every possible combination, like $FileExtsList.Add($New).
The variable are all of the same type:
$FileExtsList.GetType()
$Win_FileExtsList.GetType()
$New.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

I just don't know what I am missing.  I don't expect there will be many extensions added so performance should not be an issue.

so you're basically looking for "add or update" depending on if $DocExt exists in the array of objects or not ?

The way you are declaring it $New = ([array]@{Ext=$DocExt;...} is not correct. You are trying to cast a HashTable as an Array

In PowerShell, you can't add items to an array just like that. You have to use (for example) $Arr = @(); $Arr += $NewItem; to create an array and add items to it.

Yes, if a $DocExt is found in the file list, I increment the count for the status of the document.

As far as a hashtable, it shows above is shows the type as
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

If you want to add an item to an array then the item should match the properties. You can create a custom object like this:
$NewItem = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{Ext=$DocExt;DotExt=$DotExt;Application="update"; Active=1;Inactive=0;Skipped=0}

Then add it to existing array like this (suppose your array name is $Arr):
$Arr += $NewItem


SavindraSingh, Thank you so very much.  I am sure I tried that while I was pounding through the problem, but obviously I did not.
